# Why is this recurring function in Javascript, not working?

Tags: javascript

What is wrong with this recurrent function pattern ?
I am getting an Indentation level NaN.
My expectations were that paragraphs and j should be visible for the function next_level

```
export async function run() {
  try {
    await OneNote.run( async context => {
      var page = context.application.getActivePage();
      var pageContents = page.contents;
      var firstPageContent = pageContents.getItemAt(0);
      var paragraphs=firstPageContent.outline.paragraphs;
      //firstPageContent.delete()
      //var out_line=firstPageContent.outline
      paragraphs.load('richText/text');
      var j=1;
      // Run the queued commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion.
      return context.sync()
        .then(async function next_level(paragraphs,j) {
              //debugger;
              j=j+1;
              console.log("indentation level:",j)
              console.log("Items",paragraphs.count)
              if (paragraphs.count>0){
              console.log(paragraphs.items);
              for (var i=0; i < paragraphs.items.length; i++)
                {
                  var paragraph= paragraphs.items[i]; 
                  paragraph.load('richText/text');
                  console.log(j,paragraph.richText.text);
                  next_level(paragraph.paragraphs,j);
                }
              }
              return context.sync()
          })
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here's the OneNote context.sync documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/officeextension.clientrequestcontext?view=onenote-js-1.1#sync-passthroughvalue-)

When `context.sync` completes and calls `next_level` for the first time, it has nothing to pass as an argument. According to the documentation, the `passThroughValue` argument for `context.sync` is passed into the promise. So, you can use that, or you can to initialize `paragraphs` and `j` in the first call.

`paragraphs` and `j` are not implicitly passed into `next_level`. When you access `paragraphs` in the scope of `next_level` you are only accessing the local variables. If you want to access the `paragraphs` and `j` outside of `next_level` then you need to use different names.

Comment: I am trying to traverse a structure of paragraphs containing paragraphs so the next call must resume from where the previous stopped. How can I pass j and paragraphs to my function when I call it?

Comment: You could name paragraphs and j from the other scope differently, so you can access them inside of next_level. You could check if paragraphs is set at the start of next_level and if not set them accordingly. Or you could use passThroughValue, but I'm not sure if that works because I don't have the OneNote environment setup to test.


Maybe try calling sync like `context.sync(paragraphs, j)`